# Get field value from form and pass to web part list view filter

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2016

In SharePoint 2016, I have created an edit form with a web part in the footer area that displays list data. I would like to grab the value from the field named Start Day and then use that value to filter the list view used on the web part. So, if the Start Date is 1/11/2019, I'd like to only bring in other items that have a Start Date to 1/11/2019.

How can I do this?

Comment: What kind of webpart did you use for the form? What the form contains? Only the date by you want to filter the items?

Comment: @LukasNespor The form is just a basic Edit Form for a list called Vacation Calendar. At the bottom of the form, there is a web part shows Vacation Calendar items. However, I want to only show the items that match the currently viewed item's Start Date value.